# How go extract specific portions from a text file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, loops

I have a text file of something like following format. (steps.txt)

```
This is the first line of the file.
here we tell you to make a tea.

step 1

Pour more than enough water for a cup of tea into a regular pot, and bring it to a boil.

step 
2

 This will prevent the steeping water from dropping in temperature as soon as it is poured in.

step 3 


When using tea bags, the measuring has already been done for you - generally it's one tea bag per cup.
```

I am trying to get steps in a dictionary like
steps_dic['step 1'] = ' Pour more than enough water for a cup of tea into a regular pot, and bring it to a boil.' 
and so on.
**sometimes the step number# will be in the next line **
I am reading the file and had written a wrapper for iterator in python to parse through the lines in the code and also to check hasnext().

```
 def step_check(line,prev):
        if line:
        self.reg1 = re.match(r'^step(\d|\s\d)',line)
        if self.reg1:
            self._reg1 = self.reg1.group()
            # print("in reg1: {} ".format(self._reg1))
    if line and  prev:
        self.only_step = re.match(r'^step$',prev)
        if self.only_step:
            self._only_step = self.only_step.group()
            # print("int only step : {} ".format(self._only_step))
        self.only_digit = re.match(r'\d', line)
        if self.only_digit:
            self._only_digit = self.only_digit.group()
            # print("in only digit: {} ".format(self._only_digit))

    if self._reg1:
        self.step = self._reg1
        # print("Returning.. {} ".format(self.step))
        return self.step
    if self._only_step:
        if self._only_digit:
            # print("Only Step : {} ".format(self._only_step))
            # print ("Only Digit: {} ".format(self._only_digit))
            self.step =self._only_step+" "+self._only_digit
            # print("Returning.. {} ".format(self.step))
            return self.step
    else:
        # print("Returning.. {} ".format(self.step))
        return self.step
 with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        self.steps_dict = dict()
        self.lines = hn_wrapper(f.readlines())#Wrapper code not including
        self.prev,self.line = None,self.lines.next()
        self.first_line = self.line
        self.prev, self.line = self.line, self.lines.next()
        try:
            while(self.lines.hasnext()):
                self.prev,self.line = self.line,self.lines.next()

                print (self.line)
                self.step_name = self.step_check(self.line,self.prev)
                if self.step_name:
                    self.steps_dict[self.step_name]=''
                    self.prev, self.line = self.line, self.lines.next()
                    while(not self.step_check(self.line,self.prev)):
                        self.steps_dict[self.step_name] = self.steps_dict[self.step_name]+ self.line + "\n"
                        self.prev,self.line = self.line,self.lines.next()
```

I am able to get only 
step_dic['step 1'] = ......
step_dic['step 3'] = ..........
 but step 2 is getting missed out. I need to extract for step_dic['step 2'] also. I am not able to get how the buffer for text is leading.

Comment: The indentation is wrong, could you please [edit]? Is the entire code snippet the function definition? If so, how are you calling it (and why make a trivial thing so complex)?

Comment: Do you mean your text ends with steps?

Comment: I have edited for more clarification. Sometimes the step number will be in the next line. So I have to take next line into account. That is what challenging me. I have added method to return "step 2" though it is "step \n 2"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, the text ends with steps. but not start with steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may read the whole file into memory and then run

```
re.findall(r'^step\s*(\d+)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=^step\s*\d|\Z)', text, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OtxTdx/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `step` - a `step` word
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?=^step\s*\d|\Z)` - immediately to the right, there must be

  - `^step\s*\d` - start of a line, `step`, 0+ whitespaces and a digit
  - `|` - or
  - `\Z` - end of the whole string.

Quick [Python demo](https://ideone.com/E3L5A8):

```
import re
text = "This is the first line of the file.\nhere we tell you to make a tea.\n\nstep 1\n\nPour more than enough water for a cup of tea into a regular pot, and bring it to a boil.\n\nstep \n2\n\nThis will prevent the steeping water from dropping in temperature as soon as it is poured in.\n\nstep 3 \n\n\nWhen using tea bags, the measuring has already been done for you - generally it's one tea bag per cup."
results = re.findall(r'^step\s*(\d+)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=^step\s*\d|\Z)', text, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
print(dict([("step{}".format(x),y) for x,y in results]))
```

Output:

```
{'step2': 'This will prevent the steeping water from dropping in temperature as soon as it is poured in.', 'step1': 'Pour more than enough water for a cup of tea into a regular pot, and bring it to a boil.', 'step3': "When using tea bags, the measuring has already been done for you - generally it's one tea bag per cup."}
```

Comment: Regex this sophisticated is like wizardry, +1 from me!

Comment: Thanks Wiktor ,This is good , But I also need to capture 'step #' to store it in dict. That is what challenge is.

Comment: @john See my Python demo. You just need to prepend `step` to the digits captured into Group 1.

Comment: God level! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to include ability to detect asker's edited requirement of detecting number on following line.**

This should be able to be adjusted to achieve your goal. Basically takes regex out of the equation. This also only loads the file a line at a time (not that it matters much in this situation).

You may run into problems if you have non step-related text at the bottom of the file but should be able to be adjusted to accommodate that scenario. The other issue would be if you have steps that number into the 100s, but if you can rely on a line beginning with the word "step" (case insensitive) constituting a step, you can remove the helper function and the right half of the conditional check under the line iterator.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:

    last_key = False
    key = False
    check_next = False
    step_str = False

    my_dict = dict()

    for line in f:

        if line.strip(' \n').lower() == 'step':
            check_next = True
            step_str = line.strip()

        elif line.lstrip().lower().startswith('step') and not check_next:
            if is_int(line[-2:]) and not is_int(line.strip()):
                if key:
                    my_dict[key] = val
                    last_key = key
                    key = line.strip()

                else:
                    key = line.strip()
                    val = ''

        elif check_next and all(s == '\n' for s in line.strip()):
            continue

        elif is_int(line.strip()) and check_next:
            my_dict[key] = val
            last_key = key
            key = '{} {}'.format(step_str, line.strip())
            check_next = False

        elif key:
            val += line

    if key != last_key:
        my_dict[key] = val
```

Result:

```
{'step 1': '\nPour more than enough water for a cup of tea into a regular pot, and bring it to a boil.\n\n', 'step 2': '\nPour more than enough water for a cup of tea into a regular pot, and bring it to a boil.\n\n\n This will prevent the steeping water from dropping in temperature as soon as it is poured in.\n\n', 'step 3': "\nPour more than enough water for a cup of tea into a regular pot, and bring it to a boil.\n\n\n This will prevent the steeping water from dropping in temperature as soon as it is poured in.\n\n\n\nWhen using tea bags, the measuring has already been done for you - generally it's one tea bag per cup."}
```